# How would you identify patterns of non-ordinal text string co-occurrence across columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, string, text

I am interested in identifying patterns of co-occurrence across several columns of text strings. I have a research dataset of fixed call center data (1 call = 1 row). I have manually added 4 columns to the dataset to add tags, let's call the columns Theme1, Theme2, Theme3, Theme4.

There are around 50 tags that are text strings, non-ordinal, and use using consistent spelling (e.g., Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Violet...[44 more random colours] ...Aquamarine)

The tags are mutually exclusive across the columns. Some calls only used 1 or 2 tags. I mentioned they're non-ordinal, so I mean that a tag may occur in Theme1 in one row but then in Theme2 in another row. Here's an example:

| Theme1 | Theme2 | Theme3 | Theme4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Blue | Green | Violet |
| Blue | Green |  |  |
| Green | Red | Blue | Violet |
| Violet | Green |  |  |
| Blue |  |  |  |
| Blue | Red |  |  |

```
Expected Output 
Red AND Blue both in a row = 400
Blue AND Green both in a row = 320
Violet AND Red both in a row = 115
```

What I'd like to do is identify any common pairings across the rows. So I'd like to know how many rows have a Red and a Blue--or more appropriately ([Red then Blue] OR [Blue then Red]).

I have checked the "stacks" and I haven't found anyone trying to identify patterns across mutually exclusive, non-ordinal text strings associated. It occurred to me to use =Concatenate and simply do a manual review. And actually, that's what I'll probably end up doing...but it will take a long time and I know it has the potential to miss things.

Another thing that has crossed my mind is transposing the columns so that each column becomes a Y/N flag across 50 columns Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Violet...[44 more random colours] ...Aquamarine. Another thing that has crossed my mind is somehow writing a function that ensures the first 25 tags only occur in column Theme1 while the other 25 tags only occur in column Theme2...but even as I write this I'm not sure that would work...

What would you do?
Thanks!

Comment: From above sample data what output you expect? Can you add another column with heading `Expected Output` then put result manually and explain how the result is coming.

Comment: Are you looking for (e.g.) Red followed immediately by Blue (i.e. in adjacent columns), or could it be Red in Theme 1 and Blue in Theme 3? There are more than 1000 pairings of 50 colours BTW.

Comment: @TomSharpe the latter: simply some formula that would detect whether Red and Blue were in the same row. More broadly, a formula that would count all row combinations of 2 text strings across the 4 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the question I'm sure you won't mind me saying is rather open-ended but here are a couple of suggestions:

To find the co-occurrence of two colours in the same row, use the standard [Mmult formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-row-totals) to get row totals

```
=SUM(MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G2),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1}))
```

(I have chosen to use an array constant as we are only interested in the case where there are four columns).

[image]

You can develop this further to get for example

*Rows where colour 1 follows colour 2*

```
=SUM((MMULT(IF($A$2:$D$7=$G2,COLUMN($A$2:$D$7),0),{1;1;1;1})>MMULT(IF($A$2:$D$7=H$1,COLUMN($A$2:$D$7),0),{1;1;1;1}))
*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G2),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1}))
```

[image]

*Rows where colour 1 immediately follows colour 2*

```
=SUM(--((MMULT(IF($A$2:$D$7=$G2,COLUMN($A$2:$D$7),0),{1;1;1;1})-MMULT(IF($A$2:$D$7=H$1,COLUMN($A$2:$D$7),0),{1;1;1;1}))
*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G2),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1})=1))
```

[image]

*Notes*

Consider cell H3 in the first image above. This counts up how many rows contain both Blue and Red anywhere.

(1) build up an array comparing each element of the data in A2:D7 with G2 (Blue) using the equality operator (=):

```
=A$2:$D$7=$G3
```

Yields

[image]

(2) In order to use Mmult, the true/false array has to be converted into numbers (0 or 1):

```
=N($A$2:$D$7=$G3)
```

[image]

(3) We are going to [matrix multiply](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/matrix/multiply-matrix.php) by a column vector

```
={1;1;1;1}
```

where the semicolon is a row separator

[image]

(4) So the Mmult moves across each row in the original matrix, multiplying each element by 1 and adding them together to get row totals for each row.

```
=MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G3),{1;1;1;1})
```

[image]

(5) The other Mmult works exactly the same way and gets row totals for Red

```
=MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1})
```

[image]

(6)

Then you do a scalar multiplication of these two column vectors of row totals to find how many rows contain Red *and* Blue

```
=MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G3),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1})
```

[image]

(7)

All that's left is to use SUM to count the number of 1's in the row totals:

```
=SUM(MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G3),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1}))
```

Result: 3

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I adapted your solution and it worked. I honestly don't understand the syntax at all. I have more to learn for sure.

Comment: Hi Tom, would you mind walking me through the syntax of your first formula above?
=SUM(MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=$G2),{1;1;1;1})*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$7=H$1),{1;1;1;1}))
I am trying to understand how it works but I'd love some guidance. I have tried the Excel tutorial on array formulas, but I can't still tease apart the syntax here.

Comment: Yes of course, will add a note to my answer.